# If I hit 100% in city control, will it stay there or do I need to keep sending my assassins on missions?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

If I hit 100% in city control in *Assassin's Creed Revelations*, will it stay at that level or do I need to keep sending my assassins on missions to maintain control?

Comment: It looks like it dips a bit every day after the tally, but I'm only just now taking cities and staffing them with assassins, so this will probably take further testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can now confirm that your influence lowers each day at the income tally (just like lowered Templar influence in unconquered cities goes back up), but it's only a few percent if you have assassins stationed in the city.  Even if you control every city, it looks as though it should be trivial to keep them all maxed out if you just keep an eye on them.

Note that your maximum influence percentage appears to be based on the number and level of assassins you have assigned to that city - you'll need 5 high level assassins to reach 100% influence, but once you do it'll take forever for it to decay.

Comment: What is the level cap on my assassins?

Comment: @CyberSkull - You should ask that as another question ;)  But it's 15 for den leaders, 10 for everybody else.